# Any workarounds for getting swfupload.js working in Linux?

Tags: linux, flash, ubuntu, swfupload, uploader

SWFUpload doesn't work on ubuntu, I can see various mentions of it throughout the internets but I'm wondering if anyone here as found any work arounds?

I'm developing on Windows, so the code executes fine. But my colleague is running ubuntu, and SWFUpload crashes instantly. Has anyone encountered that and found a work around? I've tried a couple of things like commenting out things that cause known-issues like progress but to no effect.

Any help appreciated.

Dave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have problems just with large files. With bigger files flash movie freeze after some time and i need to reload page and nothing is uploaded. It is same in firefox and also google chrome. I use kubuntu 9.10. On windows there is no issue at all...

So i think that it is flash problem, because on linux uploadStart and uploadProgress events are not fired...

DO you have any workaround for this ? Flash version is 10.0 r45 (32bit on 64bit system).

Comment: Finally i've found solution and it is new flash player. With version 10.1 it is working like it should. Adobe fixed it finally after some years... eh. Download it here: http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer10.html

Answer (score 1):

be sure you are not under proxy that does not support http1.1 as you will receive an error

Answer (score 1):

make sure the folder that will handle the contents will have a chmod 777(read/write/execute) permissions.

if you type: ls -lsa
you can view all your files and folders. you will see the permissions, name, owners and etc.

in my example contents is a folder in which i will upload the files.

**4 drwxrwxrwx 2 maryon maryon 4096 2010-10-26 11:21 contents**

as you can see the contents folder which i have has rwx(read write execute) for all users. this will allow users to upload files thru SWFUPLOAD.

if you dont have this permission you can try running this: 
**sudo chmod a=rwx contents**

it means the 'a' stands for all users, will have 'rwx'(read/write/execute).

note:

1. Contents folder where you are saving
       your files.
2. 777 is not so secure,
           you can change it later and restrict
           other users(which you dont want to
           give permission to upload) on
           uploading files.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 9.04 with swfupload and everything works just fine. Might be an old flash player.

Comment: The problem is actually with an ubuntu 9.10, shouldn't the situation be "better"?